# Examples of EventKitUi or EventKit in Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am new to app development, but have developed in .Net sense inception. I was wondering if someone has any examples of how to use the EventKitUI.

My goal is to have a calendar view in my app and then if they choose to add it to their calendar they can.

I also want to be able to link to pdf documents from the content of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

> class Testclass{
>
> public event EventHandler Clicked;
>
> public Testclass{
>
> }
>
> public void FireEvent(){
>
> ```
>   if(Clicked!=null){
>      this.Clicked(this,new EventArgs());
>   }
> ```
>
> } }

Comment: looking to visually create a calendar. i have found almost no example on using the the eventkitui in monotouch